# keep running python script when a thread is waiting for stdout

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, subprocess, multiprocessing

I used python script to receive inputs and run commands on linux. One command is received in a thread, it shreds a logical volume. But sometimes it takes a long time to finish shredding a disk logical volume.

```
subproc.Popen('shred /dev/group/m1')
```

Thread in python runs one at a time. Therefore the script hangs, not taking other inputs while running the subprocess. Is there a way to solve this so that other inputs could be processed simultaneously while a thread is waiting for data from stdout?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I use this on windows:

```
os.system("start /min cmd /c C:\Python27\python.exe sino1.py")
```

see:

Python Execute Unix / Linux Command Examples
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/

Comment: `os.system()` is completely unnecessary and it doesn't answer the question (it doesn't allow to read output from a subprocess without blocking).

Answer (score 0):

- `Popen('shred /dev/group/m1')` *fails* unless you forgot to show `shell=True` parameter
- *`Popen()` does not block*, no matter how long the child process might take
- you can wait for input in multiple Python threads *in parallel*. Python can release GIL on IO.

That is, if you use `subprocess` module correctly then your script shouldn't hang.